# Java generic method that returns an instance of the passed params

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a method that has a signature like the following:

`public Dao<ClassA,ClassB> createDao(ClassA param1, ClassB param2)`

but this isn't valid Java. 
I want to create a method that receives any class creates an Dao object then returns the new object

```
public Dao<ClassA,ClassB> createDao(ClassA param1, ClassB param2) {
    //Do some stuff that creates an object of Dao<param1,param2>
    return Dao<param1,param2>;
 }
```

Any ideas on how to pull this off?

Thank you.

Comment: See @Manh's answer. You want to use Type parameters, not class instances.

Comment: The term for this is **Generics**. You can create generic methods as well as generic classes. Take a look at the [Oracle tutorial: Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public <A,B> Dao<A,B> createDao(A param1, B param2) {
    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manh answer is correct.
If you're dealing with Class objects, then

```
public <T, K> Dao<T, K> createDao(final Class<T> t, final Class<K> k) {
    return new Dao<>();
}
```